# What is the best way to recreate a xcode project file?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2

Somehow in my project, after many svn commits, merges and conflicts, my xcode project file was messed up for real.

So, I would like to recreate it, including all my source files in it.
The only naive solution that comes to my mind is to create a new project and add all my files again into it. But I'll need to recreate all my groups and organize it again.

Is that the only solution for me? Is there a easier/better solution?

**Edit**:
PS.: Xcode 4.2.1

Comment: i think there is only one solution or way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recreate the project and import all of your classes.

That is the easiest and safest way, unless you want to risk more problems down the road.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After some research, I'm convinced that this is the best way to recreate your project. I lost my project groups, so I needed to recreate and reorganize all the files again.
A tip for other people: organize your source files in file system folders, not only xcode groups. So, when you add your folders back, you can create groups for each folders again. (avoiding the need to recreate and reorganize groups).